# Split a long string by using a complete word

Tags: string, vb.net, split

I'm splitting a long string like shown below wherever it finds 'END' keyword:

```
string_end.Split(New String() {"END"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

This would perfectly split the string into multiple parts wherever it finds 'END' . But the problem arises when a string contains the word 'RECOMMENDED'. It would split it as 'RECOMM' and 'ED'. I want it to split by searching for the whole word, so that words like 'RECOMMENDED' stays as it is. Kindly help.

C# and VB.NET codes would suffice.

Comment: Just add a space before and after END as it is a word. `string_end.Split(New String() {" END "}, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Comment: @Mederic Hey thanks. worked like a charm :)

Comment: Glad I could help I'l write the answer so you can validate it :)

Comment: You need to add a space to the beginning and end of your string being searched as well...otherwise the word won't be found if it is at the beginning or end as it won't have the spaces around it.  Also, what about punctuation, like a comma or period?  You haven't given us enough details...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your simply looking for the word: END then simply add a white-space before and after:

```
string_end.Split(New String() {" END "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

After I don't recommend using split to include or exclude a line.

A cleaner solution would simply to do

```
For Each line As String In Lines
    If line.Contains(" END ") Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
Next
```

You could also use Regex but that depends if you are familiar with it.

```
Private _pattern As New Regex("\bEND\b", RegexOptions.Compiled)
For Each line As String In Lines
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = _pattern.Matches(line)
    If  matches.Count <> 0 Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `[...] but that depends if you are familiar with it` - if not, learn it!

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Yeah that's why didn't include it at first

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d(v=vs.110).aspx) to solve this:

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("\bEND\b")
Dim input As String = "RECOMMENDED AND THE END OF A STRING END"
Dim result() As String = rgx.Split(input)

'Output:
'-----------------------------
'result = {Length=3}
'(0) = "RECOMMENDED AND THE "
'(1) = " OF A STRING "
'(2) = ""
```

> The metacharacter `\b` is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.
>   There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.
>
> **source:** http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

**Why you shouldn't use spaces on a [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx)?**

```
Dim input As String = "RECOMMENDED AND THE END OF A STRING END"
Dim res() As String = input.Split(New String() {" END "}, StringSplitOptions.None)

'Output:
'----------------------------
'res = {Length=2}
'(0) = "RECOMMENDED AND THE"
'(1) = "OF A STRING END"
```

The split doesn't work with this code only the word `END` is a single word with surrounded space. But the word can be surrounded by another character or could be the beginning or end of a string:

- `END TEST` - doesn't work
- `TEST END` - doesn't work
- `TEST END, HELLO WORLD` - doesn't work
- ...